# How to configure Spring Boot 2 to run Tomcat on two ports (HTTP and HTTPS)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm not quite sure if this is possible - all examples I find online are deprecates as e.g. the property `security.http.port` does not seem to exist today in Spring Boot 2.

What I need is a way to run Tomcat on two ports e.g. 8443 for HTTPS and 8080 for HTTP.

Also I'd want everything under `/api` to require HTTPS *except* `/api/webhooks` (or at least `/webhooks` as I can still change the endpoint if I wanted).

I was imagining something like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/api/*/webhooks/**")
                    .requiresInsecure()
         .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                    .requiresSecure() 
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/*/public/**", "oauth/**")
                            .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*", "/assets/*")
                            .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/**")
                            .authenticated();
}
```

Can this be done? This question has a [background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963847/working-with-http-webhooks-when-https-is-required) - I am trying to accept webhook calls which are coming in as HTTP POST requests.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl

Comment: Hello there. I know that some time has passed but did you actually used that security configuration with the code of the answer below? I am facing the same issue but I haven't done something like this in me security configuration class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way to open http and https at same time.

Under your JAVA environment, generate a SSL key

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -dname "CN=Andy" -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 365
```

And copy the file to your resource directory

your properties should be like this

```
# https port
server.port=8443
# http port
server.http.port=8080
# key path
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
# your key password
server.ssl.key-store-password=mytest
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

Configuration for additional http port

```
@Configuration
public class HttpConfig {
    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int httpPort;

    @Bean // (it only works for springboot 2.x)
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(){
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createStanderConnecter());
        return factory;
    }

    private Connector createStanderConnecter(){
        Connector connector = 
        //new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed that worked. Although you can replace that nasty hardcoded `String` with `TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`.